# how to split json string into separate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I have a json string feeding into a mysql database from a mobile app/website and need to split it into separate rows in a new table. I currently have something like this contained in a field called oceandata:

> {\"beaches\":[{\"oceandate\": \"9/22/2014\", \"beach\":\"Doheny\"}, {\"oceandate\": \"9/21/2014\", \"beach\":\"Other\"}, {\"oceandate\": \"9/20/2014\", \"beach\":\"Other\"}]}

What I really want it to look like is:

- **oceandate  beach**
- 9/20/2014   Other
- 9/21/2014 Other
- 9/22/2014 Doheny

where `oceandate` and `beach` are my field names in the new table.

I've tried using `common_schema.extract_json_value` but have been unable to split out further into separate rows.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.